# SVN update doesn't update when run from a perl script

Tags: svn

When running the SVN update using the system command from the perl script,

system ("svn update

it doesn't update anything. All I see is the message displaying:

"Skipped "

However when the same command is run from the command-line separately, it update the folder with the SVN.

Answer (score 5):

The subversion client says "Skipped" when you try to update something that is not part of a working copy (i.e. not a folder/file that was checked out).  If I had to guess I'd say that the perl script is not properly specifying the directory/files that need to be updated, and "svn" is defaulting to the current working directory which is not a working copy.

Comment: If you did a "svn co http://.../trunk", you have a "trunk" folder in your current folder. In perl, just do a

    chdir("trunk");
    system("svn update");

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
#!/bin/perl
my $cmd = 'cd /directory/to/svn;
           svn up';
print `$cmd`,"\n";
1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It might say "Skipped: svn.example.com" if you don't have the permissions to write that directory.

Also, check your ~/.subversion directory, its owner, rights, and svn manual for svn configuration options. (In my case, this directory was owned by root for some reason.)